# AWS Gateway API as S3 proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I would like to make a REST api to access some of my resources. One of them are jsons. Being quite large, I made static files from them, and uploaded to S3. They have theirs own ids, so the structure is as follow:

```
https://MY_BUCKET_NAME/myfiles/ID/file.json
```

I made a resource in Gateway API: /myresource/{id} and GET method inside. I want my api response with content of S3 static file from:
https://MY_BUCKET_NAME/myfiles/123/file.json when accessing:
https://MY_GATEWAYAPI/myresource/123

I wanted to achieve that according to this manual:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

so I set up my myresource/{id} GET method like that:

[image]

but when I am testing this api (there is a place to insert "id") , I'm receiving:

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Comment: *"Note: To use the API Gateway console to test the API as an Amazon S3 proxy, make sure that the targeted S3 bucket is from a different region from the API's region. Otherwise, you may get a 500 Internal Server Error response. This limitation does not apply to any deployed API."* http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

Comment: I've closed your question as a duplicate of one from a year ago, but the answer there is unfortunately still applicable.  Note also that API Gateway also has a [10 MB limit on requests and responses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#api-gateway-limits), so depending on how large your "quite large" files are, this may not work, anyway.  You can alternately use a single CloudFront distribution in front of both API-GW and one or more S3 buckets, to integrate static and dynamic content under a single hostname based on path pattern matches.